# select both ways from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to select all transactions for a particular user from a loans table in mysql
i have two tables loans and users

**loans**

```
id borrower_id lender_id amnt
1  1           2         10
2  1           3         5
3  2           1         2
```

**for users**

```
id name
1  bill
2  gates
3  microsoft
```

so if i select for bill using his id 1, i should get this expected output

**output**

```
id uid name      borrower_id lender_id amnt
1  2   gates     1               2         
2  3   microsoft 1               3
3  2   gates     2               1
```

as you can see in the loans table, a user can both borrow or lend loans
this is what i tried

```
SELECT loans.*, users.name, users.id as uid 
From loans
   Left Join users On users.id = loans.lender_id 
   Left Join users On users.id = loans.borrower_id
Where
  (loans.lender_id = 2 ) Or (loans.borrower_id = 2 );
```

but am getting syntax errors

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'users'
```

**Pls i made and edit in the output**

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are joining the same table multiple times, you need to specify different aliases for it, otherwise the database engine doesn't know which one you're referring to.

Your SQL should be something like

```sql
SELECT
    loans.*, IFNULL(ul.name, ub.name), IFNULL(ul.id, ub.id) as uid 
FROM
    loans
    LEFT JOIN users ul ON ul.id = loans.lender_id 
    LEFT JOIN users ub ON ub.id = loans.borrower_id
WHERE
    (loans.lender_id = 2 ) Or (loans.borrower_id = 2 );
```

Comment: i got `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'` for your query

Comment: @Smith Sorry, it should be `IFNULL` - corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you use same table to write `JOIN` query, then you must be assign different alias to it. So that here you have to use different alias for `users` table. If same alias is there then its difficult for MySQL to differentiate both alias of user table. So you have to manually assign different alias.

You have to check for each table that there should not be `NULL` as you are using same table twice.

```
SELECT 
   loans.*, 
   IF(ul.name = NULL, ub.name, ul.name) as name, 
   IF(ul.id = NULL, ub.id,ul.id) as uid 
FROM
   loans
LEFT JOIN 
   users ul ON users.id = loans.lender_id 
LEFT JOIN 
   users ub ON users.id = loans.borrower_id
WHERE 
   ul.id = 2 OR ub.id = 2;
```